# Como mockar um metodo que possua varargs como argumentos?

Tags: java, mockito

eu gostaria de mockar esse método:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
public List<E> buscarTodos(String ... sorting) {
   Sort sort = null;
   if (sorting != null && sorting.length > 0) {
     sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, sorting);
     return defaultRepository.findAll(sort);
   }
   return defaultRepository.findAll();
 }
```

Eu já tentei de diversas formas:

```
@Test
public void testaBuscaAtestadosComFiltro() {
    List<Projeto> projetos = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
    projetos.add(projeto1);
    when(projetoServiceMock.buscarTodos()).thenReturn(projetos); 
     //when(projetoServiceMock.buscarTodos(ArgumentMatchers.<String>any())).thenReturn(projetos);
    //when(projetoServiceMock.buscarTodos(new String[] {})).thenReturn(projetos); 
   //when(projetoServiceMock.buscarTodos(new String[0])).thenReturn(projetos);
}
```

e nenhuma funcionou. alguém tem ideia do que estou fazendo errado?

Segue minha classe de teste:

```
public class ProjetoServiceImplTest {
   private ProjetoServiceImpl projImpl;

   @MockBean
   private ProjetoService projetoServiceMock;

   @Test
   public void testaBuscaAtestadosComFiltro() {
      List<Projeto> projetos = new ArrayList<Projeto>();
      Projeto projeto1 = new Projeto()
      projetos.add(projeto1);

      when(projetoServiceMock.buscarTodos(ArgumentMatchers.<String>any())).thenReturn(projetos); 
      String[] filtros = new String[] {"java"};
      projImpl = new ProjetoServiceImpl();
      List<Projeto> result = projImpl.buscaAtestadosComFiltro(filtros);
      assertNotNull(result);
}
```

E essa é a classe a ser testada:

```
public class ProjetoServiceImpl{
   @Override
   public  List<Projeto> buscaAtestadosComFiltro(String[] filtros) {
       List<Projeto> projetos = buscarTodos(); // eu quero mockar essa linha
       projetos = filtraResultado(projetos, filtros);
       return projetos ;
   }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true)
    public List<E> buscarTodos(String ... sorting) { 
        //não quero q esse metodo seja chamado!
     }
```

Comment: vc colocou a classe que você está tentando mockar, o ideal é entender a classe que está chamando ela, afinal o que a classe mocada faz não interessa muito, acredito eu, agora olhando de bate pronto eu utilizaria o Mockito.any()

Comment: Qual versão do Mockito está usando?

Comment: Coloquei mais detalhes da Classe

Comment: E qual versão do Mockito está usando?

Comment: Agora com o código completo eu vi q ta zica isso ai mesmo, nunca tinha passado por essa situação, achei ate uma issue relacionada no git do mockito. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1222

Comment: usando a versão 2.28.2, mas já tentei com a ultima também